# Create a gallery view like Photos App of iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, gallery

Does iOS provides default view like **Photos** App.

Scrolling through images, which also maintain bottom thumbnail images.

Even WhatsApp is using this same view.

I would like to know if iOS provides similar kind of view.

Here I have attached reference screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want to look at horizontal scrolling collection view.

Comment: Did u see, it is also managing bottom view which scrolling main image view. I just want to if iOS provide default view like this.

Comment: No, You have to create the collection view and then based on that you would set the image in the image view above.

Comment: What MwcsMac said. No. The OS provides enough for *you* to build something similar though.